# Django > form > is_unique()

Tags: python, django

I have the following on one of my forms:

```
def is_unique(self,item):
    ln = self.cleaned_data['letter_name']
    # checking for duplicate letter names
    if (Letter.objects.filter(item=item,letter_name=ln)):
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Is there any way I could have a `make_unique()` function that would check the name like it's doing at the moment but if an example of the `letter_name` exists it tags an `_n` (`_n` = `_01`,`_02`,`_03`) on the end of `letter_name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function should work if you call it from your is_unique function. When it is called we already know that there is at least one letter_name. Then we check how many letter_name with the tag beginning with the tagname and `_` that has been created by filtering with startswith (I guess that this only works if `_` isn't in the non altered letter_heads).

```
def make_unique(self, item, ln):
    ln_count = Letter.objects.filter(item=item, letter__startswith=ln+'_').count() + 1
    unique_ln = "{ln}_{count}".format(ln = ln, count = ln_count)
    return unique_ln
```

startswith is case-sensitive, if you want to use case-insensitive use istartswith.

Comment: I didn't think of using the contents of the `if` as a counter